# Can end-users change workflow using windows workflow foundation?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to develop a system that runs various external tools, in a specific order.
this system needs to be very dynamic, so that end-users could change this workflow in an easy manner.

I recently read few articles about Windows Workflow Foundation, and I've seen that designing the workflow is very easy for the **developer**, but that takes place inside VS environment.

Is there any way to let end-users change this workflow dynamically from "the outside", using WWF?
Are there any graphical components for editing workflows comfortably?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Workflow designer can be hosted in user application.
[Rehosting the Workflow Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489451.aspx)